# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python3

Tags: python-3.x, boost, caffe, pycaffe

I have installed libboost_python3 and am trying to link it to my program but get this error:

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python3`

Can anyone help me link to lboost_python3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find a solution to this problem in ubuntu. Just add in terminal:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py35.so /usr/lib/libboost_python3.so`

Answer (score 0):

I got some errors following the comment above because I'm using another OS and another version of python, what worked for me was:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libboost_python38.so /usr/lib/libboost_python3.so
```